DbContext get disposed after Grpc request
I'm learning ASP.NET and I'm trying to build a backend e-commerce management, at this point I have a problem with DbContext DI, right after the Grpc request the db context get disposed and it throw a dbcontextDisposed exception when trying to execute UpdateManyQuantity.
EventHandlers.cs:
using CatalogService.AsyncMessaging;
using CatalogService.Grpc.Services;
using CatalogService.Models;
using CatalogService.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Common.Models;

namespace CatalogService.Handlers;

public class EventHandlers : IEventHandlers
{
    private readonly ICatalogRepository _catalogRepository;
    private readonly IEventProducer _eventProducer;
    private readonly OrderService _orderService;
    private readonly IReservedItemRepository _reservedItemRepository;

    public EventHandlers(IReservedItemRepository reservedItemRepository, ICatalogRepository catalogRepository,
        IEventProducer eventProducer,
        OrderService orderService)
    {
        _reservedItemRepository = reservedItemRepository;
        _catalogRepository = catalogRepository;
        _eventProducer = eventProducer;
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    public void Handle(OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemToReserve = orderCreatedEvent.Items.Select(i => new ReservedItem
            {
                ProductId = i.ProductId,
                QuantityReserved = i.Quantity
            });
            _reservedItemRepository.ReserveItems(itemToReserve);
            _catalogRepository.SaveChanges();
            _eventProducer.PublishEvent(
                new ItemsReservedEvent(orderCreatedEvent.OrderId));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _eventProducer.PublishEvent(
                new ItemReservationFailedEvent(orderCreatedEvent.OrderId));
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task Handle(OrderConfirmEvent orderConfirmEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            // HERE DBCONTEXT IS ALIVE
            var items = await _orderService.GetOrderItems(orderConfirmEvent.OrderId);

            // HERE DBCONTEXT GETS DISPOSED

            //Remove the quantity from the catalog database
            var itemsProfiled = items.OrderItems.Select(i => new Item
            {
                Id = new Guid(i.ProductId),
                Quantity = i.Quantity,
                Description = i.Description,
                Price = i.Price,
                ProductName = i.Name
            });

            await _catalogRepository.UpdateManyQuantity(itemsProfiled);

            //Remove the reserved items from the reserved database 
            var reservedItems = items.OrderItems.Select(i => new ReservedItem
            {
                ProductId = new Guid(i.ProductId),
                QuantityReserved = i.Quantity
            });
            _reservedItemRepository.FreeReservedItem(reservedItems);
            await _catalogRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task Handle(PaymentRejectedEvent paymentRejectedEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = await _orderService.GetOrderItems(paymentRejectedEvent.OrderId);
            var reservedItems = items.OrderItems.Select(i => new ReservedItem
            {
                ProductId = new Guid(i.ProductId),
                QuantityReserved = i.Quantity
            });

            _reservedItemRepository.FreeReservedItem(reservedItems);
            _catalogRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Consumer.cs
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using CatalogService.Handlers;
using Common.Models;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace CatalogService.AsyncMessaging;

public class Consumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _scopeFactory;
    private IModel _channel;
    private IConnection _connection;

    private string _orderConfirmedQueue;
    private string _orderCreatedQueue;
    private string _rejectedPaymentQueue;

    public Consumer(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider scopeFactory)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        InitRabbitMq();
    }

    private void InitRabbitMq()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            Uri = new Uri(_configuration["Aws:RabbitMQHost"] ?? string.Empty),
            UserName = _configuration["Aws:Username"],
            Password = _configuration["Aws:Password"]
        };
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _orderCreatedQueue = _channel.QueueDeclare(exclusive: false).QueueName;
        _rejectedPaymentQueue = _channel.QueueDeclare(exclusive: false).QueueName;
        _orderConfirmedQueue = _channel.QueueDeclare(exclusive: true).QueueName;

        _channel.QueueBind(_orderCreatedQueue, "order", "order.created");
        _channel.QueueBind(_rejectedPaymentQueue, "order", "order.payment.rejected");
        _channel.QueueBind(_orderConfirmedQueue, "order", "order.confirm");
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        EventConsumer<OrderCreatedEvent>(_orderCreatedQueue);
        EventConsumer<PaymentRejectedEvent>(_rejectedPaymentQueue);
        EventConsumer<OrderConfirmEvent>(_orderConfirmedQueue);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void EventConsumer<T>(string queueName) where T : BasicEvent
    {
        var orderConfirmedConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        orderConfirmedConsumer.Received += (_, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var serializedBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            var clearEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(serializedBody);
            Console.WriteLine($"--> Received: {typeof(T).Name}");
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var eventHandler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEventHandlers>();
                switch (clearEvent)
                {
                    case OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent:
                        eventHandler?.Handle(orderCreatedEvent);
                        break;
                    case PaymentRejectedEvent paymentRejectedEvent:
                        eventHandler?.Handle(paymentRejectedEvent);
                        break;
                    case OrderConfirmEvent orderConfirmEvent:
                        eventHandler?.Handle(orderConfirmEvent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        _channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, orderConfirmedConsumer);
    }
}

CatalogRepository.cs
using CatalogService.Data;
using CatalogService.Models;
using CatalogService.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace CatalogService.Repositories;

public class CatalogRepository : ICatalogRepository
{
    private readonly CatalogDbContext _context;

    public CatalogRepository(CatalogDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetCatalog()
    {
        var items = _context.CatalogItems.AsEnumerable();
        return items;
    }

    public Item GetCatalogItem(Guid id)
    {
        var itemItem = _context.CatalogItems.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        return itemItem!;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsFromIdList(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        var items = _context.CatalogItems.Where(i => ids.Contains(i.Id)).AsEnumerable();
        return items;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsByName(string name)
    {
        var itemByName = _context.CatalogItems.Where(i => i.ProductName.Equals(name));
        return itemByName;
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        _context.CatalogItems.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void UpdateItem(Item item)
    {
        var selectedItem = _context.CatalogItems.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == item.Id);

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            selectedItem.Price = item.Price;
            selectedItem.Description = item.Description;
            selectedItem.ProductName = item.ProductName;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task UpdateManyQuantity(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        var resultItems = _context.CatalogItems.Where(i => items.Contains(i));

        foreach (var item in resultItems)
        {
            var selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);
            if (selectedItem != null)
                item.Quantity -= selectedItem.Quantity;
        }

        //_context.SaveChanges();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public bool ItemExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.CatalogItems.Any(c => c.Id == id);
    }
}

Program.cs
using CatalogService.AsyncMessaging;
using CatalogService.Data;
using CatalogService.Grpc.Services;
using CatalogService.Handlers;
using CatalogService.Repositories;
using CatalogService.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

//dbContext
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Aws");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>(
    options => { options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)); });

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Consumer>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEventProducer, EventProducer>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICatalogRepository, CatalogRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReservedItemRepository, ReservedItemsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEventHandlers, EventHandlers>();
//Grpc external service
builder.Services.AddScoped<OrderService>();
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapGrpcService<CatalogService.Services.CatalogService>();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
PrepDb.PrepPopulation(app, builder.Environment.IsProduction());

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

OrderService.cs
using Common.Protos;
using Grpc.Net.Client;

namespace CatalogService.Grpc.Services;

public class OrderService
{
    private readonly OrderServiceGrpc.OrderServiceGrpcClient _client;

    public OrderService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(configuration["GrpcServices:Order"] ??
                                             throw new NullReferenceException(
                                                 "CatalogService: Unable to connect to OrderService"));
        _client = new OrderServiceGrpc.OrderServiceGrpcClient(channel);
    }

    public async Task<OrderResponseGrpc> GetOrderDetails(Guid orderId)
    {
        return await _client.GetOrderDetailAsync(new OrderRequestGrpc { OrderId = orderId.ToString() });
    }

    public async Task<OrderItemResponseGrpc> GetOrderItems(Guid orderId)
    {
        var items = await _client.GetOrderItemsAsync(new OrderRequestGrpc { OrderId = orderId.ToString() });
        return items;
    }
}

In the Handler method overload with the OrderCreatedEvent param its all good so i think the problem is the asynchronous grpc request, does DI threat it as a request and it get disposed for this reason, because DbContext is registered as scoped?
Thanks you for answers.

You need a method to return _context after : _catalogRepository.SaveChanges();.  Something like my_context =  _catalogRepository,GetContext();  Then add method to CatalogRepository.  Or stop disposing the instance _catalogRepository

It would depend on what OrderService (not provided) is doing. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary abstraction going on which is undoubtedly gunking things up. It looks like the code in OrderService is using the DbContext (if so, why not just use the repository?) there is code that disposes the DbContext. The IoC container should be managing the lifetime of the DbContext so you should have no code calling a Dispose against classes managed by the container.

I provided the OrderService.cs. And it doesn't use dbcontext, it is a grpc service that calls methods on the Order microservice.
